# What is the difference between component prop and using children in Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've been playing with react-router but now I have a question that I've been unable to answer:

I understand that if you use `<Route component={SomeComponent}/>` the router uses `React.createElement` to create the new react element (see this [link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)). So if you use the hook `useEffect` it will get triggered every time right? if that is the case, if I use the recommended approach:

```
<Route>
  <SomeComponent/>
</Route>
```

The behavior of the `useEffect` should be different, shoudln't be?

Anyway, I was trying to see evidence of this with the following example:

```js
// App.js

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PropComp } from './PropComp';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Link to='/uno'>uno</Link>
        <p>...</p>
        <Link to='/dos'>dos</Link>
        <Route path='/uno' component={(props) => <PropComp {...props}/>}/>
        <Route path='/dos'>
          <PropComp/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
// PropComp.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const PropComp = () => {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('PropComp mounted')
    }, [])

    const onPlus = () => {
        setCounter(x => x + 1)
    }

    const onRemove = () => {
        setCounter(x => x - 1)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{counter}</p>
            <button onClick={onPlus}>Sum</button>
            <button onClick={onRemove}>Remove</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So at the end, I don't understand what is the practical difference between the `path=/uno`and `path=/dos`.

Also, I was reading this [post](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/react-router-what-is-the-difference-between-route-children-and-component-props/429503), so I took the [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions) of the Reac-Router docs and changed the `Route` component in order to use the prop `component` and nothing changed... for sure I'm doing/understanding something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Router>
    <Link to='/uno'>uno</Link>
    <p>...</p>
    <Link to='/dos'>dos</Link>
    <Route path='/uno' component={(props) => <PropComp {...props}/>}/>
    <Route path='/dos'>
      <PropComp/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

here

```
  <Link to='/uno'>uno</Link>
    //Link simply redirect the control to "/uno" this route. and 
    //here:
    <Route path='/uno' component={(props) => <PropComp {...props}/>}/>
   // this Defines the component for this "/uno" route



 //and your second question is that why we use these two approaches:
     <Route path='/uno' component={(props) => <PropComp {...props}/>}/>
      <Route path='/dos'>
         <PropComp/>
       </Route>
// we can use both approaches it's up to you, which one you refer, I used both
```